# BIRT Data Set Query for greater than date range from string

Tags: sql, date, syntax, birt

SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH LAST.INVOICE.DATE > 12/31/2010

The LAST.INVOICE.DATE column is coming in as a string, so I made a computed column that converted it into a date, which worked fine. Based on that, I tried a fresh query pulling from the new re-formatted DATE column which looked like this:

SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH DATE > 2010-12-31

I also tried:

SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH DATE > "2010-12-31"

Both previews are blank.

I also tried to filter the computed DATE column for > 2010-12-31 and the preview generates everything in the column regardless of date.

I'm sure I'm being an idiot, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Before

```
SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH DATE > "2010-12-31"
```

After

```
SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH DATE > to_date("2010-12-31", 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using single quotes

```
SELECT CRM.CUSTOMERS WITH DATE > '2010-12-31'
```

If that doesn't work you need to make sure you have the correct date format.